# Highmaps: format legend to 2 items for boolean values

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net, highmaps

I am using highmaps. I use it for my internal reports where I have two types of values: numeric (numbers ranging from 0 to millions) and boolean (Yes and No: Milestones). The mapping itself works to my liking for both types. Where I have a problem is whith the legend. With boolean values where it's either 0 or 1, the legend has 5 items ranging from -0.5 to 1.5.

What I am trying to do is to limit it to 2 items and/or to set a maximum limit of 1 and a minimum of 0, but I am unable to find how to do this.

If anyone has a solution or alternative, it would be greatly appreciated.

I did try a dataclass, but did not produce quite what I want:

{    $('#mapcontainer').highcharts('Map', {
                    ...
                    colors: ['rgba(19,64,117,0.4)', 'rgba(19,64,117,1)'],
                    colorAxis: {
                        dataClassColor: 'category',
                        dataClasses: [{ 
                            to: 0
                        }, {
                            from:1
                        }]
                    },
}

I would like to post an image of my code and the result I have but since I am a newbie to the site, I need "10 reputations" to do this (...not certain how to get that :/)

Comment: Can you show the code you have and any code you have tried that didn't work?

Comment: Well I have not really found anything that was remotely close to a solution; I was able to move the legend around, up down left and right, and add other properties but nothing to limit or format the number of items in it.

Comment: Updated the main question ...